# How to assign a value of different type to the field of a Pydantic model after validation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, validation, pydantic

I had a `csv` file that has youtube url and its timestamps.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsnLcaNhXd6o,0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8InLcaNhXd6o,0:43-0:52;0:56-1:07
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inji8LcaNhXd6o,0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40;0:43-0:52;0:56-1:07;1:15-1:25;1:28-1:40
```

I need to convert the `csv` file into a `pydantic` object so that I can validate the csv file and pass it to perform certain process.

```
with open(csv_file, mode ='r') as file:
        csvFile = csv.reader(file)
        csvList = list(enumerate(csvFile))
```

I'm having the following Pydantic models:

```
class TimeStamp(BaseModel):
    start_min: int
    start_sec: int
    end_min: int
    end_sec: int

class VideoDetail(BaseModel):
    row_index: int
    url: str
    timestamps: List[TimeStamp]

class VideoList(BaseModel):
    entry: List[VideoDetail]
```

Now I need to pass the `csvList` to `VideoList` model and perform some validations and get a  `VideoList` object.

First, the `list(enumerate(csvFile))` will return a `list` of `tuples` with  `row index` and `row`

`example`:

```
csvList = list(enumerate(csvFile))
print(csvList)
```

`output`:

```
[
(0, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsnLcaNhXd6o","0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40"),
(1, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8InLcaNhXd6o","0:43-0:52;0:56-1:07"),
(2, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8InLcaNhXd6o","0:43-0:52;0:56-1:07")
]
```

Now, when I pass the `csvList` to `VideoList` model, the `timestamp` will be passed as a string. But how can I pass it into a list of `TimeStamp` objects?

I tried to add a validator to the `timestamp` field in the `VideoDetail` model and split the string into a list of timestamps then return it. But it won't work as it will throw an error since, the type of the `timestamp` does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the idea is that you will have to split the timestamp string into pieces to feed into the individual variables of the pydantic model : TimeStamp

I am using a validator function to do the same.
The pre=True in validator ensures that this function is run before the values are assigned.
In the validator function:-

1. The timestamp string *(ex 0:43-0:52;0:56-1:07)* is first split by **;** to get list of strings of timestamps.
2. Then it loops through every such timestamp-string *(ex 0:43-0:52)* and splits each by **-** to get start time and end time
3. Lastly, it splits each start time and end time *(ex 0:43)*  by **:**, converts each to integer, and adds to the list

(I have used dictionary instead of tuples. You can use tuples)

```
class TimeStamp(BaseModel):
    start_min: int
    start_sec: int
    end_min: int
    end_sec: int

class VideoDetail(BaseModel):
    row_index: int
    url: str
    timestamps: List[TimeStamp]
        
    @validator("timestamps", pre=True)
    def createTimestamps(cls, value):
        timestampslist = []
        if isinstance(value, str):
            timestamplist_str = value.split(";")
            for eachTimestamp in timestamplist_str:
                start_time_str, end_time_str = eachTimestamp.split("-")
                t = TimeStamp(start_min=int(start_time_str.split(":")[0]),
                              start_sec = int(start_time_str.split(":")[1]),
                              end_min=int(end_time_str.split(":")[0]),
                              end_sec = int(end_time_str.split(":")[1]))
                timestampslist.append(t)
        return timestampslist

class VideoList(BaseModel):
    entry: List[VideoDetail]
        
csvList = [
    {"row_index":0, "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsnLcaNhXd6o", "timestamps":"0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40"},
    {"row_index":0, "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcsnLcad6d", "timestamps":"0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40"},
    {"row_index":0, "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcdshXe6o", "timestamps":"0:13-0:20;0:25-0:31;0:36-0:40"},
]

vs = VideoList(entry=csvList)
```